# Composites of homotopic maps are homotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

There is a statement, which says:

"Composites of homotopic maps are homotopic."

But there is something, what i don't understand:

1) if we got two homotopies:
$F:X \times I \rightarrow Y $ and $F': Y \times I \rightarrow Z$
How is it possible to composite them if $F$ goes to $Y$ and the domain of $F'$ is $Y \times I$ ? Should we use just $Y \times {1}$?

Comment: The second question is unclear if $f_0\sim f_1$ rel $X'$ then $f_1$  is a map on $X$ while the other homotopy implies that $f_1$ is a map with domain $Y$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't simply compose the homotopies, you construct a new one.

Suppose $f, g : X \to Y$ are homotopic via $H : X \times I \to Y$, and that $h,k : Y \to Z$ are homotopic via $H' : Y \times I \to Z$. You need to construct a new homotopy, say $K : X \times I \to Z$, from $h \circ f$ to $k \circ g$.

There's a fairly natural way to do this: define
$$K(x,t) = H'(H(x,t), t)$$
and check it has all the required properties.

I can't really tell what you're asking in your second question; I think you're using $f_1$ to mean too many things. If you clarify it I'll try to respond to that too.

Comment: I have thought of composing in a wrong way, so my second question was a bit weird. That's why I deleted it. Thanks for your help :)